# How do types inherit from libraries?

Tags: library, data-types

When you're using a library like SafeMath, and then have `using SafeMath for uint256;` within a contract, how do `uint`s know to become the `a` parameter of the library functions? Is that just a convention that applies to all functions whenever you're `using` a library for a data type?

For instance, you'd do `some_uint.sub(4)`, but the `sub` method has both `a` and `b` parameters:

```
function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the value you apply the `sub` method to automatically becomes the first parameter.

Comment: Do you know if that's the general rule when creating library functions that are used to extend data types? (That is, that the first parameter always becomes the first argument?) Couldn't find this in the docs.

Comment: Yes, if you extend data types with library functions, the value will always be the first param.